# Why do I need to use a double onClick event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, function, onclick, each

I need some clarification about the following.

Why do i need to specify the `onClick` event 2 times? (it does what i want when i do it like this) Once inside the `$('.modal').each(function()` function and once inside `$('.window-'+counter).find('input').each` function

If i only use the first `onClick` function, the `console.log` returns all the input id's from all forms on the screen.

When i only use the last `onClick` function, the `console.log` doens't return anything.

i'm trying to get the separate inputs from my modal screens. I have the following code

```
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
    $('.modal').each(function() {

//THIS PART-------------------------------------
                $(this).on('click', function() {
//----------------------------------------------

    if($( '.window-'+counter ).has('input:text').length) {
                        //console.log('first');
                        $('.window-'+counter).find('input').each(function() {

//AND THIS PART---------------------------------------------
                            $(this).on('click', function() {
//----------------------------------------------------------

                                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
                            });
                        });
                    };
               });
           });
       });
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="modal window-1" id="modal-window"">
   <div class="modal-body">
      <input class="form-control" id="sku" name="sku" type="text" value="">
      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and noticed 2 things.

1) Your HTML div with id "modal-window" has 1 unnecessary double quotes

2) It's unclear where you assign value to "counter" variable. Perhaps that's the main problem.

Otherwise you wouldn't have to use onClick event 2 times. If I get "counter" variable from $('.modal').each loop I have no problem with this code and your HTML

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //$('.modal').each(function() {
    $('.modal').each(function(modalWindowIndex,modalWindow) {
        counter = modalWindowIndex + 1; //your html modal window has class window-1, but jQuery each() index starts with 0

        if($( '.window-'+counter ).has('input:text').length) {
            $('.window-'+counter).find('input').each(function() {
                $(this).on('click', function() {
                    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
                });
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I see, I have a counter but it’s in a other function, but if I understand correctly, the .each function is run every time .modal is found? (Because of “counter = ModalWindowIndex + 1”)

Comment: Yes, each() function is run for every element with provided selector (in your case element with class "modal").


In your code you have 2 nested  each() functions.
Outer each() loops through all elements with class "modal".



Inner each() loops through all input elements within element with class '.window-'+counter.
If counter is not related to outer loop then it's meaningless to nest these 2 each() loops.



Find more info in documentation
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/